# Alguem consegue me explicar porque o 'u' no range, quando eu faço u-=1 ele conta no debug e quando vai pro range ele sobe de 1 pra 3

Tags: python

````
    for u in range(5):
      posicao_atual=lista[i][u] 
      if posicao_atual=='0':
        distancia+=1
      elif posicao_atual=='B' or posicao_atual=='A' or posicao_atual=='C' or posicao_atual=='D' :
        visitadas.append(lista[i][u]) 
        i-=1
        u-=1```
````

Comment: Não é assim que um iterador funciona no Python; talvez você esteja acostumado com o formato de repetição usado na linguagem C com o incremento à variável passada como valor inicial, mas aqui não é o caso. Independente de qualquer alteração no valor de `u` durante cada iteração do *loop*, o valor seguinte da coleção resultante da função `range(5)` é atribuído novamente à variável `u` na próxima iteração.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o for simplesmente itera na sequência, então, independente da operação que você fizer com o 'u', quando o for voltar para o início ele simplesmente vai pegar o próximo elemento que estava na sequência. Então como você falou, em certo momento da execução do seu programa temos:

```
u == 2
```

E você realiza a seguinte operação:

```
u -= 1
```

Essa operação de fato faz com que o u vire 1 naquele momento. Todavia, não altera o próximo elemento da sequência, que continua sendo 3 e, portanto, o próximo a ser atribuído ao valor de u. Se você quiser uma estrutura que tenha esse efeito teria que ser utilizado o while, visto que ele não itera sobre uma sequência, e sim sobre uma variável de controle. Então, transformando esse código em while:

```
u = 0
while u < 5:
    posicao_atual=lista[i][u] 
    if posicao_atual=='0':
        distancia+=1
    elif posicao_atual=='B' or posicao_atual=='A' or posicao_atual=='C' or 
        posicao_atual=='D' :
        visitadas.append(lista[i][u]) 
        i-=1
        u-=1

    u += 1
```

Nesse caso, o código de fato surtiria o efeito que você estava esperando.

**Adendo**:

Isso faria com que o código na próxima iteração do while utilizasse o u como sendo 2, visto que somamos 1 no final. Se quiser que o u seja 1, é só adicionar um:

```
continue
```

na linha seguinte a

```
u -= 1
```

Isso vai pular direto para a próxima iteração, sem realizar o:

```
u += 1
```

Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre o uso do for e do while clicando [aqui](https://pythonacademy.com.br/blog/estruturas-de-repeticao).

Comment: vlw mano!!!!!!!